# Java/Swing: handle simultaneous GUI and CLI input

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am creating a Swing application (a little game) where the player makes some choices clicking on Yes or No buttons and I'd like to be able to also play the game from the terminal at the same time.

What I want to achieve is that at the same time that the buttons for a choice are displayed on the GUI, some text is displayed in the CLI an I start to wait for an input with something like System.console.readLine().

The tricky part is that the player must be able to switch between GUI and CLI at any moment to do his choice.. For this reason, whenever a choice presents, I start a thread with readLine() and on the button I have attached an action listener. (But if you have another approach to solve the issue you are welcome)

So here is the problem: how can I stop waiting for user input from the CLI if the choice has been done in the GUI ?
(As expected, neither thread.interrupt() nor thread.stop() don't actually stop the readLine() from waiting for user input)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: This is a very bad idea, prefer to use a GUI with two parts : buttons, etc and a free textfield or textarea where user would be able to make rich keyboard inputs...

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would have created two Threaded classes

```
  public class MyGuiGame extends Thread { // or impelment runnalbe
      // implement run for your game model
      // you can impelemnt a game service class to be used in
  }
```

then I would create another threaded class

```
  public class MyConsoleGame extends Thread { // or implement runnalble
     // implement your console game here
  }
```

then in my appMain class in the launcher methode I would do

```
     public static void main(String[] args){
            new MyConsoleGame().start(); 
            new MyGuiGame().start;
     }
```

this is a simple idea thread based but you have to improve it using all design patterns and safe threading principals

for the input challenge you have to implement a producer consumer architecture over your data repository ( what you should read )

then you have to validate ones the common data store is not null or empty
try to look for the simple writer reader producer consumer problem.